# Access meta box checked value in another file

Tags: theme-development, metabox

So basically I need to access the value of checked() in order to load diferent template parts in my single.php file.

This is my meta box:

```
<?php

    function my_theme_add_meta_box_post_template_switcher() {

    dd_meta_box( 'my_theme-post-layout', __( 'Post template', 'my_theme' ),   'my_theme_show_post_template_switcher', 'post', 'normal', 'high' );
}

    add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'my_theme_add_meta_box_post_template_switcher');


       function my_theme_show_post_template_switcher( $post ) {
       $template = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_my_theme_post_template', true );

       // Default template for new posts
        if( empty( $template ) ) {
        $template = 'default';
}

wp_nonce_field( 'save_post_template', 'post_template' );

?>
<fieldset class="clearfix">
    <div class="post-layout">
       <label for="sidebar-left-post">
            <input type="radio" id="sidebar-left-post" name="_my_theme_post_template" value="template-1" <?php checked( $template, 'template-1' ); ?> />
            <img width="150" height="100" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/admin/images/left-sidebar.png" >
            <span> <?php _e( 'Sidebar left', 'my_theme' ); ?> </span>
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="post-layout">
        <label for="full-width-post">
            <input type="radio" id="full-width-post" name="_my_theme_post_template" value="template-2" <?php checked( $template, 'template-2' ); ?> />
            <img width="150" height="100" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/admin/images/full-width-layout.png" >
            <span> <?php _e( 'Full width', 'my_theme' ); ?> </span>
        </label>
    </div>
</fieldset>
<?php
}

function my_theme_save_post_template( $post_id ) {
    if( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) {
    return;
}

if( !isset( $_POST['post_template'] ) || !wp_verify_nonce(   $_POST['post_template'], 'save_post_template' ) ) {
return;
}

if( !current_user_can( 'edit_post' ) ) {
    return;
}

if( isset( $_POST['_my_theme_post_template'] ) ) {
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_my_theme_post_template', esc_attr( strip_tags( $_POST['_my_theme_post_template'] ) ) );
}
}

add_action( 'save_post', 'my_theme_save_post_template' );


function my_theme_get_post_template_for_template_loader( $template ) {
$post = get_queried_object();

if ( $post ) {
    $template = get_stylesheet_directory() . "/single.php";
}

return $template;

}
```

Now I need to access the checked() values so in my single.php I can load different parts according to the value checked() has, like so:

```
        switch ( $checked ) {
            case checked( $template, 'template-1' ):
                get_template_part( 'inc/post-loops/template-1' );
                break;
            case checked( $template, 'template-2' ) :
                get_template_part( 'inc/post-loops/template-2' );
            default:
                get_template_part( 'inc/post-loops/template-1' );
                break;
        }
```

Comment: How is `$current` saved?

Comment: Please don't comment, but [edit] your question with more information, what exactly you are trying to do, and what sort of file you want to output the information, where the file is, whether or not the meta filed's value is saved etc. Without proper information it is impossible from here to answer you.

Comment: Oh my god, properly indent your code.

Comment: :) Sorry.. as I pasted it got a bit messy..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't quite got a grip on the `switch` statement, [read up here](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php).

```
$template = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_my_theme_post_template', true );

switch ( $template ) {
    case 'template-2':
        get_template_part( 'inc/post-loops/template-1' );
        break;

    case 'template-1':
        get_template_part( 'inc/post-loops/template-2' );
        break;

    default:
        // Neither values matched, do something else?
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your settings are saved, per post, in the post meta fields, you can use [`get_post_meta`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/) to retrieve your settings and work on with them.

**Example:**

```
$tmplt = get_post_meta($postID, 'template', true);
switch ($tmplt) {
   case 1:
      get_template_part( 'inc/post-loops/template-1' );
      break;
   case 2:
      get_template_part( 'inc/post-loops/template-2' );
      break;
   default:
      get_template_part( 'inc/post-loops/template-1' );
      break;
}
```

Comment: No success, the switch is not having any effect..

Comment: Your data is fine? So `$tmplt` has a valid value for the switch?